# Retornar apenas valores de uma linha do banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou querendo fazer um sistema semelhante a de postagens de uma página, onde, ao clicar em uma botão da div específica, o usuário será redirecionado para uma página com informações relativas à aquele objeto. No entanto, estou tendo problemas com esse redirecionamento, pois não sei como atribuir um valor específico a variável que retorne apenas as informações de uma linha do banco de dados, ocorrendo - ao clicar - a amostragem de todos os dados de todas as linhas e colunas do banco de dados.

Pensei em resolver o problema da seguinte forma: ao clicar no botão da div, o script irá atribuir um valor para uma variável, que deverá ser igual ao valor da id da postagem no banco de dados, de forma a limitar os resultados, mas não consigo criar esse botão.

Essas são as informações de comunicação com o banco de dados, e as informações que eu quero retornar:

```
include("conectar.php");

$consulta = "SELECT id, nome, sexo, idade FROM teste
where id = '3'";

$con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);
```

E essa é a tabela que deve retornar as informações:

```
     <tr class="header">
        <th style="width:10%;">ID</th>
        <th style="width:60%;">Nome Completo</th>
        <th style="width:10%;">Sexo</th>
        <th style="width:10%;">Idade</th>
        <th style="width:10%;">Acesso</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $dado["id"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dado["nome"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dado["sexo"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dado["idade"]; ?></td>
        <td><a href="teste/pagina1.php"><div class="acesso">Acessar</div></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $dado["id"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dado["nome"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dado["sexo"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dado["idade"]; ?></td>

    <td>
      <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="idlink" value="<?php echo $dado['id']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form> 
    <td>
```

Adicionar um form na celula do botao;

Na pagina php pegar o valor do id com $_POST['idlink']